# Create full date column from year and isoweek columns

Tags: julia

I would like to create a column with a full date having year column and isoweek column, so in the third column aa.date and first row I'd like to get 2023-07-30. Any ideas which package to use?

```
using DataFrames, Dates

aa = DataFrame(Year = [2023,2023,2023], isoweek = [31,32,33])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using DataFramesMeta.jl:

```
using DataFramesMeta

@transform(aa, :date = Date.(:Year, 1, 1) .+ Dates.Week.(:isoweek .- 1))
```

Output:

```
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Year   isoweek  date       
     │ Int64  Int64    Date       
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │  2023       31  2023-07-30
   2 │  2023       32  2023-08-06
   3 │  2023       33  2023-08-13
```

Comment: This code does not return a date in a correct isoweek week AFAICT.

Answer (score 2):

Your code, unfortunately, does not seem to by fully correct (the point is that the first week of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday of the year, which can result in dates prior to January 4th being in the last week of the previous year).

Therefore for your method you have:

```
julia> aa = DataFrame(Year = [2020,2021,2022], isoweek = [31,32,33])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ Year   isoweek
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼────────────────
   1 │  2020       31
   2 │  2021       32
   3 │  2022       33

julia> @. Dates.firstdayofweek(Dates.Date(aa.Year,1,2)) - Dates.Day(1) + Dates.Day(7 * (aa.isoweek - 1))
3-element Vector{Date}:
 2020-07-26
 2021-08-01
 2022-08-07

julia> @. week.(Dates.firstdayofweek(Dates.Date(aa.Year,1,2)) - Dates.Day(1) + Dates.Day(7 * (aa.isoweek - 1)))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 30
 30
 31
```

Also in your solution you find Sundays (is this what you want?) while the first day of ISO week is Monday AFAICT:

```
julia> @. dayname.(Dates.firstdayofweek(Dates.Date(aa.Year,1,2)) - Dates.Day(1) + Dates.Day(7 * (aa.isoweek - 1)))
3-element Vector{String}:
 "Sunday"
 "Sunday"
 "Sunday"
```

So the way to do what you want would be (I have not optimized it, but it should be fast enough):

```
julia> firstday(y, w) =
    Date(y) + Day(findfirst(x -> week(x) == w, Date(y):Date(y+1)-Day(1)) - 1)
firstday (generic function with 1 method)

julia> firstday.(aa.Year, aa.isoweek)
3-element Vector{Date}:
 2020-07-27
 2021-08-09
 2022-08-15

julia> week.(firstday.(aa.Year, aa.isoweek))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 31
 32
 33

julia> dayname.(firstday.(aa.Year, aa.isoweek))
3-element Vector{String}:
 "Monday"
 "Monday"
 "Monday"
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: thank you Bogumil, you are right isoweek starts on Mon but I've been looking for Sun as a first day (that was missing in my description), anyway thank you very much for detailed explanation and solving that!

Comment: if you are looking for Sunday then just change to `findlast` in the code above (as in iso week standard Sunday is last day of week).

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, maybe will be helpful for someone, if you know better solution then please add

```
Dates.firstdayofweek(Dates.Date(aa.Year,1,2)) - Dates.Day(1) + Dates.Day(7 * (aa.isoweek - 1))
```